# Failed To Activate Control 'vb.usercontrol' In VB6

Tags: user-controls, vb6, runtime-error

I have a program which is written in VB6 and runs in many PCs with different windows versions, without any problem.

But in some PCs it does give me the error:

```
failed to activate control 'vb.usercontrol'. this control may be incompatible with your application
```

I register OCX files which are needed by my program.

I don't know if it's related to being a *32bit* or *64bit* OS or not.

I'll be happy to know your answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem and the solution :

There is an ocx file which has two version, and my program has been built with the new version and some PCs had the old version.

so there was a mismatch between two files.

Now, I replaced the old ocx with the new one and the problem solved.