# Error: Failed to activate control 'VB.userControl'. This control may be incompatible with your application

Tags: vb6, user-controls, runtime-error

I was getting the error:

> "Failed to activate control 'VB.userControl'. This control may be
>   incompatible with your application. Make sure you are using the
>   version of the control that was provided with your application. after
>   installing two applications."

I noticed that after I first installed one application, it was working fine. I can launch the first program and use it.

However *after I installed the second application* and restart then launch the second program. *It gives me the error on the first program upon launching it*.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the first application and launch it again, it will work but the second application will now get the error.

I saw another answered question with the same error here however I think mine is quite different as I am dealing with two applications.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed To Activate Control 'vb.usercontrol' In VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453297/failed-to-activate-control-vb-usercontrol-in-vb6)

Comment: Most likely the two different programs are installing different versions of some dependency. Another question had a similar problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453297/failed-to-activate-control-vb-usercontrol-in-vb6  Without more details its quite hard to help you debug this, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have the source code to the two programs you are having trouble with? Can you determine from that what their dependencies are?

Comment: That was the question I found here where I tried to check the ocx or dll between the two application. I tried and played with it. Updated the old ocx but to no good. The dependencies are mostly ocx or dll.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to what used to called "DLL hell".  You have two applications installing two versions of the same DLL (or OCX, same thing).  If you know which .dll or .ocx file is the source of the problem, you can use one of several DLL or COM redirect techniques.  I have used the ".local" approach to force a VB6 application to load a specific version of an OCX:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-redirection

Good luck!

Comment: Yes that is the problem. I dont know which dll or ocx causing the problem. I will read on the link you provided. Thanks a lot tcarvin!